# NServiceBus : No destination specified for message(s):

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus

I just created a new NServiceProject as specified in this link:

http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856687-getting-started---creating-a-new-project

But after running the project, I am getting following error

`"No destination specified for message(s):".`

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have created ASP.NET MVC type project.

Comment: Have you deployed your service message to the MVC host?

Comment: @stephenl. No. The link does not talk about it. I am running the application using Visual Studio. How can i deploy the service to the MVC host ?

Comment: Have a look at the section that talks about deploying components. It says "Right-click the SubmitOrderSender component, choose "Deploy to...", and then pick the ECommerce endpoint from the drop-down."

Comment: @Stephenl: Yes, I did that. I am not sure what is the problem. I have followed all the instructions.

Answer (score 7):

The NServiceBus "No destination specified for message:" typically results from a missing or incorrectly defined routing configuration.

In order for NServiceBus to find the proper destination queue for a message, the routing configuration must define the delivery mapping. The routing can be defined for commands, types or events.

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing

The following snippet shows a routing example for NServiceBus 6:

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
var routerConfig = transport.Routing();
routerConfig.RouteToEndpoint(
    assembly: typeof(MyMessage).Assembly,
    destination: "my.nservicebus.queue");
```

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me find the 3 different ways to register (aka, the RouteToEndpoint call) .. future readers see : https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/nservicebus-step-by-step/3-multiple-endpoints/

Answer (score 2):

You should specify endpoint config:

```
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="InternalMessages.Commands.SendOrderConfirmationEmail, InternalMessages" Endpoint="ExternalGateway.Salesforce" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

Comment: I think this is a much cleaner way to add the mappings and should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you might have done, but it sounds like you have missed a step somewhere. I followed the tutorial and created a working copy for your reference, I hope it will help you identify the issue.

https://github.com/sliedig/NServiceBusStudio.Amazon.Demo

Answer (score 0):

It was because you missed the step to add the NServiceBus Host endpoint:

Go ahead and create another endpoint called OrderProcessing as an NServiceBus Host.